# How to upload second version of app on app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload second version of my app on app store i create new bundle id distribution certificates then i go to iTunes connect on iTunes connect i select bundle id from drop down menu "Note that the Bundle ID cannot be changed if the first version of your app has been approved.I stuck here?

Comment: Why did you change bundle id? You have to increase version instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the documentation please you must read  [Updating Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1)

No need to create new bundle id distribution certificates just follow the Following steps:

- Go to you **Itunes Connect**--> **Login**--> **Manage Your Apps**-->click on you app icon that yo want to upload new version.
- click on add Version

[image]

- After this there is one window open that asking for version Number and what new in this version like following screenshot:

[image]

- Now open Xcode and open the project that you want to upload set same version number that you are setting in itunesConnect.
- Set the Bundle number and version number that must greater then previous one for Example bellow screenshot.
- Set correct code sign and also set correct Bundle Identifier that you are setting previous for distribution.

[image]

- Now you can upload this with two way from **Xcode**->**selectDevice**->**Product**-->**archive**--> After create Build that organize window open there is two Option **Validate And Distribute** select Distribute and Login with you itunes id password there is appear you currunt Version that you are setting and follow step by step there Intruction.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this link(apple documentation )
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change your Bundle ID if you want to update your app. The bundle ID AFAIK identifies your app from others, so changing your ID is the same as changing your App.