# How to create a second version of current app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm new to the iOS Development! I want to create an app for iOS devices. I know it's nice time to learning more about iOS Development with Swift. But I have a little problem with it. My problem line is version of app. Let's assume I have a fully completed app of version first. Assuming it's already been distributed by App Store. So, I want add a new features and improvements to my current app, from this point I'll need to build a second version of app. Let's say this version 1.1, successor of the 1.0.

Questions:

1 )  How to create a second version of app?

2 )  I'll need to rebuild everything from scratch?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can either just update your current code and submit that for version 1.1, or if you really do feel like starting from scratch you can do so as well, apple wont care so long as it gets through their review process

Comment: That's ok! Thanks. So if I have submitted version of 1.1 and users are able to getting from the App Store. As free of charge. Let's say my app much like to iOS Notes App! And I have used Core Data Framework. You can guess by framework name, what I mean. If users are updated to the latest version of app for example version 1.1. Their data will be lost? Sorry. I'm beginner and younger. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the data doesnt necessarily have to be lost, if you are using core data there are ways of upgrading the old database to a new one, im sure there are tutorials on how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in order to submit an update to your app, you just modify the code as you like, update the version and build number of the project and submit it just as you did when you uploaded the app for the first time.

As for your second question, just read this document by Apple and you'll be all set :) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html

Answer (score 1):

For your first question,please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383545/how-to-upload-second-version-of-app-on-app-store?rq=1) carefully.

For second question, I think there is no need to rebuild everything from scratch.Normally, your next version is based on your previous version.

Comment: Please, try to include in your response the relevant part of the solution. Feel free to link to external resources in addition to the response itself.

Comment: @JoseGómez Thx, I am a fresh man of StackOverflow. My english is poor, perhaps I am not catch the point of this question, but I hope help solve this question.

Comment: Hi BirdV, the problem is not the language. What I suggested is to include the relevant points the solution in the response, and not just provide a link with the solutions. Links can change or break over time, so it's better if you put the solution in the response itself.

Comment: @JoseGómez Thks again!